# Pass value from an android activity to javascript page in phonegap/Cordova

Tags: android, cordova

As the title says

I have a Cordova plugin class.I invoke an activity from there.I have some functions happening in that activity class.Need to give the value back to the javascript interface.How can this be done?

```
                Log.i("logger", "entered java code");

                JSONObject arg_object = args.getJSONObject(0);
                Log.i("logger", "entered java code");

                MapValues mapValues=new MapValues(arg_object);
                Log.i("logger", mapValues.toString());
                Activity context = this.cordova.getActivity();

                Intent intent=new Intent(context,MapsActivityConsumer.class);
                Bundle mbBundle = new Bundle();                    
                mbBundle.putParcelable("main_json_object_mapvalues_key", mapValues);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.putExtras(mbBundle);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this.

```
            this.appView.loadUrl("javascript:sendValuetoJS(\""+mapValues+"\");");
```

where sendValuetoJS is the method name you want to call. In that method you return the value from Native.

I am using this to send values from Native to PhoneGap.

Comment: could you please elaborate on what library you are importing for "appView"

Comment: appView is nothing but your webView.